# FabricJS: fabric.Image.filters.RemoveColor is not a constructor

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to use filters for an image, specifically the RemoveColor filter.

I have this working for Invert...

```
var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Invert();
object.filters.push(filter);
object.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

But using this code for RemoveColor...

```
var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveColor({
  color: color.rgb,
  threshold: this.props.currentRemoveColorDistance,
});
object.filters.push(filter);
object.applyFilters();
canvas.renderAll();
```

returns this error...

> Uncaught TypeError: fabric.Image.filters.RemoveColor is not a
>   constructor

If I `console.log(fabric.Image.filters)`, I can see that the RemoveColor property is indeed missing, but there is a RemoveWhite instead...

```
BaseFilter
Blend
Brightness
ColorMatrix
Contrast
Convolute
GradientTransparency
Grayscale
Invert
Mask
Multiply
Noise
Pixelate
RemoveWhite
Resize
Saturate
Sepia
Sepia2
Tint
```

After trying RemoveWhite, it works but of course, only the white is removed which is not what I want.

Where is RemoveColor?

I am using npm "fabric": "^1.7.22"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove color is fabric 2.0 only and has been created from removeWhite.

You have to switch to fabricjs 2 in order to use it.

http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes#image

at this link you find information on how to transition Image and Filters, and generally things you should know.

Comment: Ok, is fabric 2.0 on npm?

Comment: it is, with the rc tag. Be aware is 2.0 because there are backward incompatibilities, in special way on images and filters.

Comment: Can you please add a link because I can't seem to find it. I am not sure what you mean by rc tag. What do I need to add to my packages file?
 Thanks